# Problem with initializing a struct of a span

Tags: c++, embedded

I have the following structs:

```
struct Point {
    const uint16_t time;
    const uint8_t sp;
};

struct SPProfile {
    const char label[12];
    const etl::span<const Point> profile;
};
```

I have some arrays of these `Points`:

```
const Point profile1[] = {
        {0, 10},
        {1, 20},
        {2, 30},
};
const Point profile2[] = {
        {0, 100},
        {1, 200},
        {2, 300},
};
```

Now, I want to create an array of `SPProfiles`, which store `span`s to the `Point` arrays. I thought this should be possible like this:

```
const SPProfile profiles[] = {
        {"Profile 1", profile1},
        {"Profile 2", profile2}
};
```

I don't see the problem with this, but apparently my compiler does. It says:

```
error: could not convert '(const Point*)(& profile1)' from 'const Point*' to 'const etl::span<const Point>'
```

However, I can create an array of these `span`s perfectly fine, e.g. like this:

```
const etl::span<const Point> profiles[] = {profile1, profile2};
```

However, when I want to initialize the *struct* containing this same span, this does not work anymore.

What is going on here?

BTW, I'm using `etl::span` from the [Embedded Template Library](https://www.etlcpp.com/) here, which is analogous to `std::span`.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/8dfrc15r7) (using either `std::span` or `etl::span`). You did have a narrowing conversion (300 can't fit in a `uint8_t`) but after I changed that it compiles. What compiler are you using?

Comment: What happens if you call the constructor explicitly: `etl::span<const Point>(profile1)`?

Comment: @Kevin I'm using gcc-arm-none-eabi 5.4.1 (from PlatformIO). Yeah, I see the narrowing conversion. The real code is different, but I simplified it a bit (and didn't pay attention to the size)

Comment: @Lundin That appears to work! Interesting. Why do I have to call the `etl::span` constructor explicitly in this case?

Comment: @Kevin I see now that it fails with GCC 5.4.1, but it works with GCC 7.2.1. Is my compiler too old? What feature is it missing exactly?

Comment: @Compizfox Seems to be an issue that was fixed in GCC 6. You should consider upgrading. GCC 5.4 is from 2016.

Comment: I was thinking this would be a namespace hiccup in case `using etl::span` isn't present, then the compiler has no idea which constructor to pick.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, yes, I'll look into it. GCC 5.4.1 is the default toolchain in PlatformIO for arm-none-eabi.